# Does each assembly language correspond to one instruction-set-architecture?

Tags: cpu

This is a quote from [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language):

> Each computer architecture has its own machine language. Computers differ in the number and type of operations they support, in the different sizes and numbers of registers, and in the representations of data in storage. While most general-purpose computers are able to carry out essentially the same functionality, the ways they do so differ; the corresponding assembly languages reflect these differences.

However, “computer architecture” is often meant to denote “instruction set architecture”. If that is what is meant here then I understand the quote. **Or do we need multiple assembly languages for different architectural implementations of the same instruction set?**

Comment: Yes, assembly language depends on the ISA; indeed, it’s a reflection of the ISA. I suggest learning some assembly language (for a particular ISA) - that would clear things up.